# Uploading an image to file system using Node.js

Tags: node.js, post, express, crud

I am trying to upload an image to my server through a node.js server using express. I am in the process of writing an CRUD API but I am stuck on how to POST and save the image in a directory on my server.

```
//post
app.post('/public/media', function(req,res){

});
```

This is the barebones of my post method. I am trying to store the image in my media file. How should I go about this?

Note, I am not trying to store the image into a database. Rather, I am trying to store the image in a folder on my server and simply store the path to the image in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Without duplicating an entire article about this issue, [checkout this tutorial out](http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-and-resizing-an-image-using-node-js/). You will need to make slight adjustments to this code if using Express 4, otherwise it will work great.

Comment if you have issues below.